# Rearrange windows in bottom taskbar

Tags: gnome-shell

The windows of opened applications can be switched between by clicking on the tabs in the bottom taskbar of the desktop. In Ubuntu 20.04, these tabs cannot be rearranged by clicking and dragging them like they can be in Windows. What can be done to make the tabs rearrangeable br dragging them?

Comment: Are you referring to the Dock or the top bar?

Comment: @24601 The one at the bottom.

Comment: In a vanilla 20.04 LTS installation, the bar is at the top. please [edit] your question to indicate what change you have made to get it at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

You can move icons in the Ubuntu dock, but indeed the intension is different. Once you move an icon, it is turned into a favorite, i.e., an icon that stays on the dock, and always on the same spot, even if the application is not running.

It is how the extension is currently designed. To change that, you could file an issue to [the project](https://micheleg.github.io/dash-to-dock/). Developers of the project may then consider your idea and eventually implement it at a future point.

Comment: Not that. The one at the bottom where open windows are shown.